# Datetime format not displaying the Date and Time

Tags: coldfusion, spreadsheet

I am exporting excel file  of a database table and its giving me ##### on the date and time format columns .

```
<cfquery name="ArtOrders" datasource="#application.dsn#">
SELECT * FROM Table
</cfquery>
<cfset xlssRegistrant = SpreadsheetNew("Registrant",true) >
<cfset SpreadsheetAddRows(xlssRegistrant, ArtOrders)>
<cfset col1 = {dataformat = "mm/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss"}>
<cfset SpreadsheetFormatColumns(xlssRegistrant, col1, "7-8")>
<cfheader name="Content-Disposition" value="attachment;filename=SIGHTINGS.xlsx">
<cfcontent type="application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet" variable="#spreadSheetReadBinary(xlssRegistrant)#">
```

I'v formatted the column But still I am getting the date time in the **#####**

Comment: what value displays when you highlight the cell in excel? if you don't set as date field what value is shown?

Comment: You should delete your other question on the same topic.

Comment: From your other question - It looks like December 30, 1899 happens to be the base date for several Microsoft products. [What is story behind December 30, 1899 as base date?](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/f1eef5fe-ef5e-4ab6-9d92-0998d3fa6e14/what-is-story-behind-december-30-1899-as-base-date?forum=accessdev).  Maybe this will help - [How to Work with Dates Before 1900 in Excel](http://www.exceluser.com/formulas/earlydates.htm). Or Google for similar solutions.

Answer (score 1):

In my experience this is simply an issue with the width of the column and excel not wanting to show partial info. Try expanding the column width after opening the file to ensure the date then shows correctly. If so, just use SpreadsheetSetColumnWidth to set the initial width of that column to be larger.

Comment: i did this but it's not issue with columns.